# ImageMagick is installed, but php extension of Imagick is not enabled

Tags: imagemagick, system, exec, imagick, passthru

Hy there,
I have a shared hosting account. They installed Image Magick on my request. But I get this error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Imagick' not found in /home/hamrohos/public_html/test.php on line 6

I told them what was wrong. They replied

> ImageMagick is installed, but php extension of Imagick is not enabled on shared accounts

Now my question is Can I use Image magick or its any features if its php extensions are not enabled?

Currently I am using GD library but it doesnot have all features of image magick.

I have following features disabled too.
phpinfo(), exec(), system(), passthru()

Answer (score 0):

Without enabling ImageMagick extension in PHP, you won't be able to use the functions it providesdirectly.

The only way to use ImageMagick in this scenario would be to call it with a **system** function and execute everything as a shell script. You would have to save the image data on disk to do this and after processing them with imagemagick, you would have to load them again.

Thus, It would definitely be feasible, but with severe overhead and changes to your scripts.

Comment: Thanks but I guess system functions are also disabled in my server.